# Hadoop MultiNode Cluster Set up - Data not getting loaded to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distributed

I am trying to set up a multinode cluster (Hadoop 1.0.4) and all the daemons are coming up. I have a 2 node Cluster with a Master and one Slave. I am configuring only slave as datanode.

1. I did change the core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml , Master(with Master IP) and slaves file (with slave IP).
2. Configured passwordless ssh and copied it to authorized_keys , copied Master public key to slave authorized_keys.
3. Formatted Namenode

I could see all daemons - Namenode, Jobtracker and Secondary namenode running in Master and TaskTracker,Datanode on Slave machine.

But when I try to load the data to hdfs using **hadoop fs -put** command I am getting the following error

```
15/09/26 08:43:33 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Exception closing file /Hello : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /Hello could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
```

I did an **fsck** command and got the below message.

```
FSCK started by hadoop from /172.31.18.149 for path / at Sat Sep 26 08:46:00 EDT 2015
Status: HEALTHY
Total size: 0 B
Total dirs: 5
Total files:    0 (Files currently being written: 1)
Total blocks (validated):   0
Minimally replicated blocks:    0
Over-replicated blocks: 0
Under-replicated blocks:    0
Mis-replicated blocks:      0
Default replication factor: 1
Average block replication:  0.0
Corrupt blocks:     0
Missing replicas:       0
Number of data-nodes:       0
Number of racks:        0
```

Somehow Datanode is unavailable to the Namenode, but I couldnt figure out why.

Any help is appreciated . Thanks!

Comment: Check the logs of both NameNode and DataNode and you will find the reason why DataNode is not able to connect to NameNode.

Comment: have you changed the replication factor to 2 ?

Comment: yes, I changed the replication factor

Comment: Hadoop client somehow is not able to talk to datanode for write operation. Please check the logs to get precise error